# Express sequence in closed type

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Given the sequence $a_n = \sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}$. Is there anyway to find a closed form for this sequence?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm only guessing here, but is there any chance the ultimate goal is to study the convergence of this sequence?

Comment: Probably no closed form, but maybe you don't need a closed form to do whatever it is you really want to do with that sequence.

Comment: Not really, I know that the sequence converges to 2 and it is really easy to prove but i want to have a closed form of this in order to get rid of this a(n-1) term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_0=0$ then,
$$a_n=2\cos(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}})=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+....\sqrt{2}}}}$$

Where there are $n$ $2's$ on the right hand side.

This can easily be shown through the use of the trigonometric identity $$\cos(2x)=2\cos(x)^2-1$$

Taking the limit as $n$ tends to infinity shows that the nested radical clearly converges to two,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}2\cos(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}})=2$$

Comment: Τhank you really much for your fast and straightforward answer. I'd like to ask a couple of questions. Is there any way to express the sequence in a closed form without using π? And what if a(0)=sqrt(2) ? What would be the closed form then?

Comment: @agelaki11, in the case you suggested $\hat{a}(0) = a(1)$, so every other element can be similarly represented.

Comment: If $a_0=\sqrt{2}$, then $a_n=2\cos(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+2}})$. And I think this is probably as 'good' as you are going to get in terms of a closed form.

Answer (score 0):

We are given
$a_n = \sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}$.

I will assime that
 $0 \le a_0 < 2$.

If $a_{n-1} < 2$,
$a_n < \sqrt{2+2} = 2$,
so all subsequent $a_n < 2$.

Since $a_1 = \sqrt{2+a_0} < 2$,
all  $a_n < 2$.

Let $d_n = 2-a_n$,
so $a_n = 2-d_n$.

$2-d_n = \sqrt{2+(2-d_{n-1})}
=\sqrt{4-d_{n-1}}
$
or,
since $1-x < \sqrt{1-x} < 1-x/2$
if $0 < x < 1$,
$d_n 
= 2-\sqrt{4-d_{n-1}}
= 2-2\sqrt{1-d_{n-1}/4}
< 2-2(1-d_{n-1}/4)
= d_{n-1}/2
$
so
$d_n \to 0$
geometrically,
so $a_n \to 2$.

Comment: OP already knows the sequence converges to 2, see the comments. This doesn't engage with the question actually asked.